# Can I create a non-clustered index on my SQL Server 2012 Primary Key?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table defined:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Text]             NVARCHAR (4000)  NULL,
    [GlobalId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Question] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionId] ASC),
);
```

Is it possible for me to drop the clustered index on the primary key, create a non-clustered index and then create a clustered index on GlobalId? If so how can I drop it when it's already defined as a constraint and how could I recreate it with the non-clustered?

Also am I right in thinking that having a clustered index on GlobalId will be the most efficient way to do a look up by GlobalId ?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes - of course you can do this! Just read the extensive and freely available on-line documentation ("SQL Server Books Online") for the details of the command syntax.... However, putting the **clustered index** on a GUID column is a horribly bad idea due to the resulting index fragmentation. If I were you, I'd **leave the clustered index on the `INT IDENTITY`** - that's **much better** for your system health and performance!

Comment: See **WHY** you shouldn't put a clustering key on a GUID column:   http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx, http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx, http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx, http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx

Comment: thanks guys. I will read up on the why.

Comment: Apart of marc_s's very good comments, I want to say that a PK doesn't allows NULLS. So, if you try to create a PK constraint on GlobalId this will fail because at this moment this columns allows NULLs.